# Как создать svg-дугу между блоками?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, svg

У меня есть несколько блоков, некоторые из них связаны друг с другом (как потребитель и расчеты). Необходимо по клику на один из связанных блоков нарисовать дугу, соединяющуюся с другим блоком таким образом, чтобы учесть: 
1. Дуга не должна касаться текста под иконками или другой дуги (рисовать вверху/внизу). 
2. При ресайзе окна дуга также соответственно меняет свои размеры. 
3. Совсем идеально — с анимацией появления этой самой дуги.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чтобы ничего особо не считать можно воспользоваться не дугой, а кривой Безье

Comment: Да, но для этого мне также нужно подобрать координаты для каждой отрисованной дуги так, чтобы соблюсти условия

Comment: @GunAlv а конкретно что не устроило в моём ответе ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, хороший ответ, но он не учитывает переполнение текста. При определенной ширине экрана линия все равно пересекается с текстом

Comment: докажите что текст пересекается - покажите скрин

Answer (score 5):

Fill и иконки - сможете поставить ?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 330" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .fo{
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  
  <g transform="translate(0,40)">
  <line x1="50" x2="850" y1="100" y2="100" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4" 
        stroke-dasharray="4 4"/>
  
  <circle cx="210" cy="100" r="50" />
  <circle cx="380" cy="100" r="50" />
  <circle cx="560" cy="100" r="50" />
  <circle cx="730" cy="100" r="50" />
  <circle cx="900" cy="100" r="50" />
  
  <foreignObject x="170" y="155" width="100" height="160" class="fo">
    In the context of SVG embedded
  </foreignObject>

  <foreignObject x="340" y="155" width="100" height="160" class="fo">
    In the context of SVG embedded
  </foreignObject>

    <foreignObject x="520" y="155" width="100" height="160" class="fo">
    In the context of SVG embedded
  </foreignObject>

  <foreignObject x="690" y="155" width="100" height="160" class="fo">
    In the context of SVG embedded
  </foreignObject>

  <foreignObject x="860" y="155" width="100" height="160" class="fo">
    In the context of SVG embedded
  </foreignObject>
  
   
  
   <path d="M50,100 C0,100 400,500 730,100" 
         fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="4 4"/>
     
  <path d="M380,100 C380,100 580,-200 900,100" 
        fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="4 4"/>
   <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="6" fill="orange"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```